# Add margins to the side in TexShop editor

Tags: margins, editors, texshop

Is it possible to add side margins to the editor of TexShop?

Just in the editor, I'm not interested in the output. If I for example start editing some text in fullscreen, a paragraph fills the complete width of the screen from left to right. Which is not very convenient or visually appealing for editing long reports.

I'm actually just starting with tex, so any other hint on increasing the usability while writing is welcome!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm not sure if there is a setting for the margins (other than 'don't use full screen') but you can put newlines in the paragraphs yourself. LaTeX ignores single newlines so this does not change the output - only double newlines, i.e., an empty line, are taken into account to start a new paragraph in the output. Putting manual newlines is also useful for version control (git etc.) because it shows in more detail which parts of the text have changed between versions.

Comment: While TeXShop doesn't support set margins you can use a hard return as mentioned above on the right and then if you add space on the left (e.g., a tab or two) the hard return will return to that left margin. However, if you use a soft return on the right (i.e., you just keep typing and let TeXShop wrap the line) the text will go to the far left margin.